# Nuxt 3 hide /api, /api/** routes from the browser after proxying

Tags: javascript, proxy, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 3 plugin `myPlugin.server.js` where I map all my api routes(routes are external, on a different backend) `await Promise.allSettled(apiRoutes.map(async (route) => {const data = await $fetch(route.url)...})` and populate Pinia stores on server. And I have a server middleware to proxy those requests:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const url = event.node.req.url;

    if (url.includes('/api/') && url !== '/api/health' && url !== '/api/_sitemap-urls') {
        const pathRewrite = url.replace('/api/', '/');

        await proxyRequest(event, (process.env.WP_API_URL || 'http://localhost:1222/wp-json') + pathRewrite);
    }
});
```

After proxying request I want to hide the `/api/**` routes from the browser and send 404, but the problem is that after proxying `/api/**` routes are not reachable as they are proxied and if I `sendRedirect()`, I get error `Can't send headers after they are sent`. And if I send 404 before proxying, proxy breaks as it receives 404 on `api/**` routes.

I tried to create route `server/api/` and send redirect there, but no luck. I also tried to create a route on the client and route middleware with `navigateTo()`, but nothing worked, as this routes are proxied and they are not reachable on the client.

How can I implement that?

Thank you.